# JQuery Fade In after Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, fadein

I am trying to get my main logo image to fade in (using Jquery) after a certain delay.

The script actually works fine EXCEPT that when you 1st load the page, the ENTIRE page falls under `style="display:none"`

I ONLY want the logo to `display:none` not the entire page. Is there something I am missing? Some tag I am not closing? Here is the link: [My Website](http://madeclothiers.com/)
And here is the code [Javascript]:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logo').delay(1500).fadeIn(1500);
});
</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<img src="img/made_clothes2.png" class="clothingLogo" id="logo" style="display:none;" />
<center><ul class="social">
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/madeclothiers"><img src="img/facebook.png" class="social"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/madeclothiers"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="social"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.madeclothiers.tumblr.com/"><img src="img/tumblr.png" class="social"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://web.stagram.com/n/madeclothiers"><img src="img/instagram.png" class="social"></a></li>
</ul></center>
```

As it stands now, when the page load NOTHING shows until the delay.fadeIn() is executed... I want the other "social" images to load and the #logo to load independently on its on [using the delay.fadeIn()].

Thanks,
[edited: I fixed the img tag and ul tag, but still no go on the image "social" images loading]

Comment: `img` is an empty tag and should not have the closing tag. And also `center` is very, very deprecated

Comment: @MattWhipple Nope that didn't work, I originally thought that was the problem, so I that is why I included that `</img>` tag

Comment: Works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/f9G6h/4/ but you should fix the img tag.

Comment: Maybe remove the "display:none;" from the style and use $("#logo").hide(); before the fade in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated answer, one which actually works
modify your jquery script to the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logo').css({ opacity: 1});
});
```

add this to your css

```
.clothingLogo {
    opacity: 0.001;
    transition: opacity 1.5s 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s 1.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.5s 1.5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1.5s 1.5s;
    -khtml-transition: opacity 1.5s 1.5s;
}
```

remove all styling from image

```
<img src="img/made_clothes2.png" class="clothingLogo" id="logo" />
```

tested firefox and chrome, if you want you can find some other way to express opacity for antique ie versions...

Comment: No problem, anytime I'm around

Answer (score 3):

there is no `</img>` tag. make it `<img src="img/made_clothes2.png" class="clothingLogo" id="logo" style="display:none;" />`.

The browser probably chokes on that and therefore doesn't display anything else.

I found your problem. In your stylesheet you set:

```
ul.social{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: -12%;   // <- problem is here
  text-aling: center;
}
```

when `#form` is hidden, `ul.social` is at the top of the page. with `margin-top: -12%` it is **12% above the visible area**........

PS: send beer and cake to my house AND VALIDATE YOUR HTML!

Comment: I tried that as well... and still `display:none` dominates everything below it.

Comment: I see no reason for everything else being hidden. check your CSS!

Comment: I have checked your website code and I agree with Gung Foo. You need a slash at the end of the tag (Notice it after the style="display:none;")

Comment: @kpsuperplane I added the slash at the end of the img tag, and still no go on the getting just the logo image to `display:none`

Comment: @GungFoo yes I have. And when I take off the `fadeIn()`, nothing loads... because it is all being controlled by that `display:none`

Comment: @GungFoo Yep that was the problem and it did solve my problem but @xception method works too w/o me having to change the layout, so I am going to use his. 

I have to use the `-12%` because my designer gave me an image in which the canvas is too big and pushes the image below the fold... but I will check to see if I can get an image cut a little tighter and see if this code works.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just a thought but I suggest you set width and height for that logo image in your css, and also try using `opacity: 0.001` instead of `display: none` in it's style, you might find it works better because the image gets a download request the moment the browser hits the img tag, not when jquery starts switching opacity

```
<img src="img/made_clothes2.png" class="clothingLogo" id="logo" style="opacity: 0.001; width: 1024px; height: 768px;" />
```

Comment: @MattWhipple that should work too, I just prefer the opacity way since that's the thing jquery will play with anyway :)

Comment: I tried that `opacity` trick and it did fix my social buttons, but now the logo image does load at all... so I returned it to the `display:none`

Comment: @Shade try `visibility: hidden` as MattWhipple suggested

Comment: I tried `visibility: hidden` but that didn't work either.... it forces the entire logo image to never be shown. Should I change the javascript to match the new call?

Comment: @Shade may I ask what browser are you using to test these?

Comment: @xception I am using Google Chrome (in privacy mode) and Safari to check the outcome on a 13' Macbook Pro Lion (latest)

Comment: @Shade added a new answer since this one had already too many comments and they wouldn't make sense for this one

Comment: @MattWhipple really disappointed by jquery behaviour on this, I really expected my original answer to work, I'm usually using mootools though so I got totally unexpected behaviour here

Answer (score 1):

Actually `img` tag should be as follows

```
<img src="img/made_clothes2.png" class="clothingLogo" id="logo" style="display:none;" />
```

and you can use following javascript instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#logo').fadeIn(1500);
        }, 1500);
    });
</script>
```

And also your `<ul>` tag should have a closing tag like `</ul>` and use `css/style` to center your `ul` instead of using deprecated `<center>`.